# on click image slider open in cloudbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<a href="image_full.jpg" id="pirabox_gal1" ><img src="addtocart.png" width="150" height="50" /></a>
<a href="#" id="pirabox"><img src="addtocart.png" width="150" height="50" /></a>
```

i have image and when i click on this image, i want open full image on same window in box and background image with cross button. please help me and tell complete process. i have java script pirabox but when i apply this on my image, image open but not open like  a box.

Comment: Could you post some code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need some kind of lightbox script. There are a variety of jQuery lightbox plugins, such as [fancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#instructions), [jQuery lightBox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/), [slimbox](http://www.digitalia.be/software/slimbox2) and [colorbox](http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/). Each of these sites have their own documentation for set up and usage.

Comment: i don't know about. can you tell how i do this